# Google calendar API for tasks

Tags: google-calendar-api

I can't find on Google Calendar API reference a way to retrieve tasks as shown on image...

[image]

But if I inspect the http requests there is some way to retrieve the calendar tasks...

[image]

Is there a way to retrieve Google Calendar tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you can use the following methods:

- [**list**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/v1/reference/tasklists/list) to return all the authenticated user's task lists.
- [**get**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/v1/reference/tasklists/get) to return the authenticated user's specified task list.

Note: Using this methods requires [authorization](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/v1/reference/tasklists/list#auth) with at least one of the following scopes:

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks.readonly`

Hope that helps!